# AWS batch limit number of container on single host

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have some containers with GPU Tensorflow jobs, and, if 2+ of them are executed simultaneously on a single host, only 1 will succeed (`2018-05-11 13:02:19.147869: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:171] Internal: failed initializing StreamExecutor for CUDA device ordinal 0: Internal: failed call to cuDevicePrimaryCtxRetain: CUDA_ERROR_ECC_UNCORRECTABLE`, i.e. they cannot share GPUs properly).

Perfect scenario would be like following: I have 10 GPU jobs and max 5 containers. First 5 are executed, other 5 wait (at the moment, they don't wait but try to execute and fail), when one finished, 6th immediately starts on the same host, then 7th, 8th, 9th, 10th.

I use p2.xlarge, and set up 4 vCPU and 42000 memory for gpu job. According to ec2instances.info, this machine has 61.0 GiB memory and 4 vCPUs. But, anyway, batch seems to schedule several containers simultaneously, leading to described failure.

So far I tried to play with `vCPU` and `memory` parameters, but Batch's scheduler seems to ignore those.

Interesting that relevant ECS task definition has `1/--` as value for `Hard/Soft memory limits (MiB)`, so looks like **values from Batch 'job defition' are not propagated to ECS 'task definition'**.

Another alternative is to setup a very big number of attempts, but

- it's ugly
- for long-running jobs even big number might get exhausted
- I lose defense from forever-running jobs (e.g. mis-configured)
- not sure how that kind of interruption would affect already running Tensorflow jobs